# Firebase Query (multiple value)

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

How do I perform a query in firebase with multiple query? Which mean I like to give multiple value to compare in database and get the match result.

```
var db = firebase.firestore();
    var routeRef = db.collection("RouteInfo");
    var queryResult = routeRef.where(("origin", "==", origin1) && ("destination", "==", destination1) && ("departureDate","==" , departureDate1 )).get().then(function(snapshot){
        snapshot.forEach(function(doc){
            $("#routeResult").append(/*something inside to show the match result*/);
        });
    })
    .catch(function(error){
        console.log("Error fetting documents: ", error);
    });
```

Sorry I had no experience in web development.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way you can add multiple `where()` function calls using `&&` operator. So to solve this, please change the following line of code:

```
var queryResult = routeRef.where(("origin", "==", origin1) &&
    ("destination", "==", destination1) &&
    ("departureDate","==" , departureDate1 )).get().then(function(snapshot){/* ... */}
```

to

```
var queryResult = routeRef.where(("origin", "==", origin1)
    .where("destination", "==", destination1)
    .where("departureDate","==" , departureDate1)).get().then(function(snapshot){/* ... */}
```

Chaining multiple `where()` functions, as explained above, works perfectly fine when it comes to Firestore.